# How do I enable :recoverable in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

By default, the forgot password in Devise doesn't actually send a password reset link to email and I know the `:recoverable` module is what needs to be enabled/implemented.

I have tried searching for tutorials or guides in google and here in stackoverflow but no success.

Where can I find a good example or what code do I need to enable it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To enable the `recoverable` module, pass it as a symbol to the `devise` method.

```
# in user.rb

devise :recoverable # add other modules, separated by commas
```

For example, your devise configuration might look something like this.

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, :recoverable
```

You should also add `reset_password_token` and `reset_password_sent_at` columns to your `users` table. You can do it with a migration.

```sh
rails g migration add_recoverable_fields_to_users
```

And in the generated migration file, add the following.

```rb
def change
  add_column :users, :reset_password_token, :string
  add_column :users, :reset_password_sent_at, :datetime
end
```

Comment: the problem is, I don't know what to do next after that. I mean, I don't know what steps do I need to take next like should I do migrations, generate new controllers, define methods? If you don't mind, I would like to know what should I do after that.

Comment: @jeramaedybohol Updated. See if it helps.

Comment: After adding devise recoverable module in the model as above, go to configuration for :recoverable section in `config/initializers/devise.rb` file and update values for `reset_password_keys`, `reset_password_within`, and `sign_in_after_reset_password` or other available configurations as available for your version.

Comment: In addition of the changes to the User model and the configuration, you also need to do a db migration to add fields required by recoverable, which you can get from here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-an-already-existing-table-to-add-devise-required-columns